# How to append the content of a file to a filename?

Tags: unix

I'm trying to achieve something like below.

I have a file called `file_number` and another file called `serial_number` which is containing a number inside it. Let's say 1.

Now, I want to append this number 1 from the `serial_number` file to the name of the my existing file called `file_number`. So, i want it to become `file_number_1`

How to do this in Unix??

Comment: I was trying `cat file_number serial_number > file_number_${serial_number}` but that is appending inside the file but not to the name..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking to do this:

```
mv "file_number" "file_number_$(cat serial_number)"
```

Example demonstration:

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ touch file_number
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ echo 1 > serial_number
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat serial_number
1
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 nicolaw  staff  0 25 Oct 14:07 file_number
-rw-r--r--  1 nicolaw  staff  2 25 Oct 14:07 serial_number
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ mv "file_number" "file_number_$(< serial_number)"
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 nicolaw  staff  0 25 Oct 14:07 file_number_1
-rw-r--r--  1 nicolaw  staff  2 25 Oct 14:07 serial_number
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $
```